# No module named importlib error in ironpython

Tags: c#, ironpython

Please bear with me if my question sounds silly but drafting this question after my own research.

In my framework, I have installed two Nuget packages 1.IronPython and 2.IronPython Standard Lib to run Python file through C#. Below is the small code snippet which I am using:

```
ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
earchPaths.Add(@"<site-packages path>");                                 
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
var script = @"C:\Images\Dummy.py";
var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(script);
var eIO = engine.Runtime.IO;
var errors = new MemoryStream();
eIO.SetErrorOutput(errors, Encoding.Default);
var results = new MemoryStream();
eIO.SetOutput(results, Encoding.Default);
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);
```

When I execute above code I am getting error 'no module named importlib'. However, in my Dummy.py file I am using only cv2 library (import cv2 as cv) but do not know why i am getting error with importlib.

Solutions I tried:

1. In search path added site-packages path from folder where Python is installed
2. In search path added Lib path from folder where Python is installed
3. In search path added site-packages path from folder where Iron Python Standard Library nuget is installed
4. In search path added Lib path from folder where Iron Python Standard Library nuget is installed

Please let me know what solution can i try to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Is it in this C# file or the python file? Which line is it on? If it's in the python file can we see the contents of that as well?

Comment: Try removing Standard Lib which is c language and not c#.

Comment: Thank you all for your response!
I have resolved this issue by adding one more search path where importlib was installed.
But now I am getting error 'unexpected token 'from''. Anybody have any solution on this please? 
There is nothing wrong in Python file, I am able to run it through Command Prompt. Getting this issue when I am running it through Iron Python.